# Same Product But Adds Another Row in Table (Javascript only)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, product

I have a simple problem. When i add a product to cart and add the same product to cart again, it adds another row. It should just increase its quantity. Hoping for your answer. This will be a big help for me. Please use only pure JAVASCRIPT. No JQUERY. Thank you guys.

```js
    //var qtyTotal = 0;
    //var priceTotal = 0;
    var products = [];


    function addProduct() {
        var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
        var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
        var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        // qtyTotal = qtyTotal + parseInt(qty);
        //document.getElementById("qtyTotals").innerHTML=qtyTotal;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

      var newProduct = {

          product_id : null,
          product_desc : null,
          product_qty : 0,
          product_price : 0.00,
      };
        newProduct.product_id = productID;
        newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
        newProduct.product_qty = qty;
        newProduct.product_price = price;


        products.push(newProduct);

        //console.log("New Product " + JSON.stringify(newProduct))
        //console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products))

        var html = "<table border='1|1' >";
        html+="<td>Product ID</td>";
        html+="<td>Product Description</td>";
        html+="<td>Quantity</td>";
        html+="<td>Price</td>";
        html+="<td>Action</td>";
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        html+="<tr>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_id+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_desc+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_qty+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+products[i].product_price+"</td>";
        html+="<td><button type='submit' onClick='deleteProduct(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Delete Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addCart(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Add to Cart</button></td>";
        html+="</tr>";
    }
        html+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

        document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()            
}
    function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
        for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
               products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    function addCart(product_id){
      var html = '';
      var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");     
      if(ele.innerHTML == '')
      {
        html+="<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
        html+="<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
        html+="<td>Product Description</td>";
        html+="<td>Quantity</td>";
        html+="<td>Price</td>";
        html+="<td>Total</td>";
        html+="<td>Action</td></tr>";
      }
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            products[i].product_qty = parseInt(products[i].product_qty) + 1;
            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_id+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_desc+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_qty+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+products[i].product_price+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+parseInt(products[i].product_price)*parseInt(products[i].product_qty)+"</td>";
            html+="<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\""+products[i].product_id +"\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button></td>";
            html+="</tr>";
        }    
    }
      
      if(ele.innerHTML == '')
      {
        html+= "</table>";
        ele.innerHTML = html;
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById("tblCart").innerHTML += html;     
      }      
    }
    
    function subtractQuantity(product_id)
    { alert(product_id);
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id & products[i].product_qty >= 1) {
            products[i].product_qty = parseInt(products[i].product_qty) - 1;
        }

        if (products[i].product_id == 0) {
            removeItem(products[i].product_id);
        }
        console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products));
        
    }
}

function removeItem(product_id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
            // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
            products.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart Pure Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="productID">Product ID:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="productID" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="product">Product Desc:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="product_desc" name="product" type="text" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="quantity" name="quantity" width="196px" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="price" name="price" size="28" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddProduct" onclick="addProduct();" value="Add New Product" >


</form>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p> <br/>
<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="demo2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the scenario here? Does your products array contain a list of products and your cart a list of instances of the product, like in a normal shopping cart? If so whats the point of the quantity property for product?

Comment: @kobi-wan-kenobi. At first, you can add the product information including its quantity. After that you can add it to cart and it displays it to the table. Once you click the add to cart button of that same product, it just increases its quantity. If different product is added to cart, then that would be the time to add it to another row in the table. I manipulated the Product ID but still doesnt work. Hoping you can help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are trying to store your products and cart items in the **SAME ARRAY**. The cart should contain **instances of the product**, not the other way around.

Secondly, you keep adding to your html table without ever taking away the previous row (for the same product).

Thirdly, you cast your price variable to Integer, monetary values should always be float or double.

I assume you where looking for something like the following:

```
var products = [];
        var cart = [];

        function addProduct() {
            var productID = document.getElementById("productID").value;
            var product_desc = document.getElementById("product_desc").value;
            var qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

            var newProduct = {
                product_id: null,
                product_desc: null,
                product_qty: 0,
                product_price: 0.00,
            };
            newProduct.product_id = productID;
            newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
            newProduct.product_qty = qty;
            newProduct.product_price = price;


            products.push(newProduct);


            var html = "<table border='1|1' >";
            html += "<td>Product ID</td>";
            html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
            html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
            html += "<td>Price</td>";
            html += "<td>Action</td>";
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_id + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
                html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='deleteProduct(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\", this);'/>Delete Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addCart(\"" + products[i].product_id + "\", this);'/>Add to Cart</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;

            document.getElementById("resetbtn").click()
        }
        function deleteProduct(product_id, e) {
            e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
                    products.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        function addCart(product_id) {


            //Indentify the product and add it to new "cart" array
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    var cartItem = null;
                    for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                        if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {//Already exists in cart, increment quantity.
                            cartItem = cart[k];
                            cart[k].product_qty++;//Increment by one only, as requested.
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (cartItem == null) {
                        //Every item in the cart specifies the product in question as well as how many of the product there is in the cart, starts off at product's quantity
                        var cartItem = {
                            product: products[i],
                            product_qty: products[i].product_qty // Start of at product's quantity
                        };
                        cart.push(cartItem);
                    }

                    break
                }
            }

            renderCartTable();

        }

        function renderCartTable() {
            var html = '';
            var ele = document.getElementById("demo2");
            ele.innerHTML = ''; //Start by clearng your table of old elements

            html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
            html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
            html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
            html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
            html += "<td>Price</td>";
            html += "<td>Total</td>";
            html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty) + "</td>";
                html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Quantity</button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";
            ele.innerHTML = html;
        }

        function subtractQuantity(product_id)
        {
            alert("Removing 1 instance of product "+product_id);
            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                    cart[i].product_qty--;//decrement by one
                }

                if (cart[i].product_qty == 0) {
                    cart.splice(i,1);//Remove from cart
                }
                console.log("Products " + JSON.stringify(products));
            }
            //Finally, re-render the cart table
            renderCartTable();
        }

        function removeItem(product_id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                    // DO NOT CHANGE THE 1 HERE
                    products.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

This Will Start off your cart on the quantity specified from the product, then increment/decrement by one from there on.

Comment: Sir you're a big help to me. This is what Im looking for. I'm just starting my studies in javascript. Thanks a lot sir. BTW, can you make the grand total below the shopping cart? Thank youuuuuuuuu

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of javascript, best of luck in your studies. You can calculate the total easily in the renderCartTable() function, Id suggest giving it a try yourself first, you will learn more that way. ;)

Comment: Its ok. You've been spoon feeding me. LOL. Ill try it on my own. In this way ill be able to learn faster. Thanks a lot sir